# Collapsable Navbar using jquery and bootstrap, doesn't work on mobile phone, shows correctly on desktop

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design, navbar, collapsable

I have coded a collapsable navbar using bootstrap and jquery that works fine locally on my desktop, but doesn't collapse once I upload it onto the internet. Neither the button appears nor the links work anymore.
I have tried it on Safari 6.1.2, Firefox 43.0.2 and Google Chrome Version 47.0.2526.106 (64-bit).

As said before everything works fine on the desktop. Links start to break down, though, on the iPad and it doesn't work at all (neither collapsing navbar nor links) on my iPhone (Safari, JavaScript is enabled).

I have checked with a script link to a mobile-jquery-version, put jquery.min.js before the bootstrap.js,all the scripts are in the right folder on the internet. Cannot find my mistake. 
I am new to bootstrap, jquery, javaScript. Is there anybody out there who could help me with it?

Thank you!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>TransCoding–An Arts Research Project</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
 <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script> 
<![endif]-->

<!-- include jquery, bootstrap and my stylesheet -->

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/styles-kug.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> 


</head>

<body>

 <div class="container"> 

    <div class="col-md-12">

        <h1>
        TransCoding
        </h1>
    </div>

</div>
```

```
    <!--start of collapsed navbar -->

        <div class="navbar-header"> 
            <button
            type="button"
            class="navbar-toggle collapsed"
            data-toggle="collapse"
            data-target="#main_navbar"
            aria-expanded="false"
            aria-controls=main_navbar">Menu
            </button>
        </div> <!--/end of collapsed navbar -->

        <!--start of un-collapsed navbar -->
        <div 
            class="collapse navbar-collapse" 
            id="main_navbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

            <li class="active"><a class="link_hover" href ="index.html"> ABOUT </a></li>
            <li><a href = "english/team.html">TEAM </a></li>
            <li><a  href = "english/methodology.html">METHODOLOGY</a></li>
            <li><a  href = "english/researchquestion.html"> KEY RESEARCH QUESTIONS</a></li>
            <li><a  href="english/blog.html"> THE BLOG "WHAT-IFBLOG.NET" </a></li>

            <li><a  href="english/links.html">LINKS </a></li>
            <li> <a  href = "english/contact.html">CONTACT</li></a>


        </ul>
        </div> <!--/ end of un-collapsed navbar -->
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have kept looking and found this information on stack overflow:

Add to the header

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

It works perfectly well, thank you stack overflow.